# Can not change the timezone for phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to insert some data into the database where the table has a column of `date` which is of type `timestamp` and a default value of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

I've tried the following methods to change the timezone:

Inside the php-5.6.ini file, modified these lines:

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = America/Los_Angeles
```

Saved the file and called `sudo service httpd restart` as well as `sudo service mysql restart`. I'd also like to note i"m using an ec2 instance if that has any effect.

I'm using the slim framework, so I've tried calling `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');` inside the `index.php` file, still no change.

The clock is always an hour behind, whether I set the timezone to America or Asia.

Also tried `ini_set('date.timezone', 'Asia/Singapore');`

Tried calling `SET time_zone = 'America/New_York'` inside mySql work bench but returns `#1298 - Unknown or incorrect time zone:`. Therefore, inside terminal I called `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo` which seems to do something, but doesn't actually change anything. Still the same issue

Answer (score 1):

`php.ini` settings do not change the timezone of your mysql server. It change the timezone for apache server only. To change the mysql timezone issue the command:

```
SET time_zone = 'America/New_York';
```

from mysql terminal. This will automatically change the date/time obtained from all the `TIMESTAMP` fields.

If you want to do it from php, then instead of the default `timestamp` value pass the value from php like:

```
$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

and insert the value of `$datetime` in `timestamp` column.

Comment: Seem to have the issue of `Unknown or incorrect time zone`, regardless of the timezone im entering

Comment: That is because `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql` **only generates a SQL script** that you then need to capture and load into the server, and then the server may need to be restarted, since time zone metadata lookups are cached.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot how do I "capture and load into the server"?

Comment: `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo > load_tz_data.sql` then import the generated `load_tz_data.sql` file into the `mysql` schema.